Azure DevOps pipeline fails with [error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'
I am trying to run pytests using Azure DevOps pipeline.
          - task: PipAuthenticate@1
            inputs:
              artifactFeeds: '<Feed Name>'

          - script: |
              pip install --upgrade pip
              pip list
            displayName: 'Verify Pip Authentication'

          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: |
                pip list
                pip install -r "$(BuildSolution)/${{project}}/PythonClient/requirements.txt"
                pip list

The PipAuthenticate task succeeds (Successfully added auth for 1 internal feeds and 0 external endpoint). However, pip install task fails with the following error
##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.

##[debug] Arguments: '/D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\__w\_temp\48c8fe5b-fcd8-40b5-b055-2f08fddc1d7f.cmd""'

##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'

##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'C:\__w\1\s'

"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\__w\_temp\48c8fe5b-fcd8-40b5-b055-2f08fddc1d7f.cmd""

##[debug]Exit code: 1

##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.

##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue correlationId=79cfa0e8-4c20-4dbc-823f-165b1da5a276;source=TaskInternal;type=error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected

##[debug]Leaving C:\__w\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.237.1\cmdline.ps1.

I have enabled the debug logs on the pipeline. There are no additional logs being displayed to debug this error. Is there a way to print additional logs that will help debug this issue further?


Did your pipeline fail at "Verify Pip Authentication" step? 2. Is your pipeline running on a MS-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent? If you are using a self-hosted agent, please try MS-hosted agent, for example, vmImage: windows-latest. If it works on a MS-hosted agent, then try to run the same pip install --upgrade pip command directly on your local machine and check what's the result. 3. What's the version of your python and agent?


Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT. 1) It fails at "Verify Pip Authentication" step. 2) It runs a MS-hosted agent. The commands works fine in my local machine. 3)  python version 3.9 is being used.

I can't reproduce your issue in my pipeline. To narrow down the issue, you can 1. Create a new pipeline and just run the same scripts as in "Verify Pip Authentication" step. If it works, add a PipAuthenticate@1 task and check what's the result.  2. If it works after adding PipAuthenticate@1 task, then we can know the problem isn't related to the scripts shared by you.  Share the completed yaml file of your pipeline, then I can test and investigate further on my side.
